# Magento 2 - Delete from custom Model

Tags: magento2, model, delete

I am trying to delete a record in my custom table (custom model).
I can do it like this:

```
$mymodel = $this->mycustomFactory->create();
$mymodel->load($id);
$mymodel->delete();
```

But I need to specify two fields to load by:

$id & $customerId

In MySQL it would something like:

```
DELETE FROM mycustomtable where id = $id AND customer_id = $customerId;
```

But I only want to delete this record, not load it fully.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you need to use collection filter over there by those 2 fields.

Comment: If you dont want to load them and it's a custom model just... execute the query instead of loading the collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I didn't want to use direct SQL I ended up creating a collection and then looping through and deleting:

```
$myCollection = $this->myCollectionFactory->create()
    ->addFieldToFilter('attr1', array('eq'=> 'aaa')
    ->addFieldToFilter('attr2', array('eq'=> 'bbb'))
    ->addFieldToFilter('attr3', array('eq'=> 'ccc'));

$myModelFactory = $this->myModelFactory->create();
foreach ($myCollection as $myModel) {
    $myModelFactory->load($myModel->getId());
    $myModelFactory->delete();
}
```

Not sure if this is the correct way but it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
           $customModel= $this->customModel->create();
            $customModelClone = $customModel->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect('*')
                ->addFieldToFilter('coupon_code',['like' => "$othervar%"]);
                
            if ($sku == null) {
                $customModelClone;
            } else {
                $customModelClone->addFieldToFilter('sku',['eq' => $sku]);
            }

            if ($customModelClone->getSize() > 0) {
                foreach ($customModelClone  as $custom) {
                    $custom->delete();
                }
            }
```

for me in magento 2.4.3 use `Company\CustomModule\Model\ModelFactory`, if use `load()` it will fail, but if you not use `load()` and foreach after `addFieldToFilter()` it will be successfully removed (able to multiple data)

I hope this helps